# Setting givenname and surname for each sAMAccountName in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

i want to change for user `JohnDoe` the givenname from `john` to `John` 
this is my csv (real csv has more than 100 lines):

```
surnameNew,sAMAccountName,surname
Doe,JaneDoe,doe
```

i want to change for user `JaneDoe` the surname from `doe` to `Doe`

i tried this:

```
Import-csv $path | %{
    Set-ADUser $_.sAMAccountName -Surname $_.surnameNew
}
```

It says identity parameter is null.
How can i achieve my goal?
Can you guys tell me why identity is null?

Comment: Have you done some basic debugging? Printed out `$_.sAMAccountName` and tried to run the Command without the pipe and with hardcoded input?

Comment: Yeah i tried it with hardcoded input. It worked. printing out `$_.sAMAccountName` returns like the error says null

Comment: Try `(Import-Csv -Delimiter ',' $path).sAMAccountName`

Comment: The error is correct `$_.sAMAccountName` is null. Will be hard to troubleshoot this as it is likely an issue with your source data. Column name spelled correctly? Actual nulls in there possibly? You should just try and print it out first to know for sure. `write-host "'$($_.sAMAccountName)'"`. Is your source file comma delimited? heck, does `Import-csv $path` print out anything?

Comment: @Paxz comma is the default delimiter so that should not change much.

Comment: @Matt thx for the tip with `Import-csv $path`. It was a delimiter issue which i couldn't see cuz i edited the csv so  there was not any delimiter in the csv which i could see. With `Import-Csv $path` the PowerShell console showed me which delimiter it is.